# System of differential equations with three functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve following system of differential equations:

$$
\begin{cases} (2D+11)x+(D+3)y+(D-2)z=14 e^t \\
(D-2)x+(D-1)y+Dz=-2 e^t\\
(D+1)x+(D-3)y+(2D-4)z=4 e^t
\end{cases}
$$

Where $x=x(t)$, $y=y(t)$ and $z=z(t)$?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: Laplace-transform everything and solve it as a system of linear equation. Then you'll find the expressions for $X, Y, Z$ to reverse transform.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments, I thought if there is a way other than L-Transform like matrix diagonalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one general technique for systems of equations like this is using [Laplace Transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).

However in this case try the substitutions :

$$x = A_1e^t+A_0$$
$$x = B_1e^t+B_0$$
$$x = C_1e^t+C_0$$

Where $A_0, B_0, C_0, A_1, B_1, C_1$ are all constants.

And you should end up with what sounds like a lot of work, six linear equations, but actually it's two sets of linear equations in three variables each.  But they are easy to solve.  However that might not be the general solution to the set.  The Laplace technique would get you that.

http://www.codecogs.com/library/maths/calculus/differential/linear-simultaneous-equations.php